# SOQL - Most recent date that is less than today

Tags: soql

How would you go about getting the most recent date from a set of records that is less than today?

Example:
Record_1 = 1/1/2016
Record_2 = 2/1/2016

If you did a soql like:

```
Select Id FROM Object Where Date < TODAY
```

You would get back both of the dates.

How do I get back just the 2/1/2016 date?

Comment: If there are two records with the `2/1/2016` date, would you want to return both of those records, or just one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a couple clauses:

```
SELECT Date__c FROM Object__c
WHERE Date__c < TODAY
ORDER BY Date__c DESC
LIMIT 1
```

- The `ORDER BY` clause makes sure you get the most recent result first.
- The `LIMIT` clause makes sure you only get one result.

So if you wanted a method that returns just the `Date` value it would look like:

```
public static Date getMostRecentXBeforeToday()
{
    return [/*query*/].Date__c;
}
```